# Apply get_group() when groupby used multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I applied Pandas groupby to a dataframe to get all available combinations of a few fields as follows:

```
list_of_fields = [field1, field2, field3, field4]
grouped = df.groupby(list_of_fields)
```

This works as expected and when I print the groups in `grouped.groups` I get the right tuple combinations.

Now I need to use the groups in `grouped` to create multiple dataframes with the rows that match the values for each of the groups (basically, splitting my original dataframe). However, I do not know how to do this. I have tried the following:

```
for key in grouped.groups.keys():
    partial_df = grouped.get_group(key)
```

But this is giving me a key error. Is this because the keys are multiple fields? How could I make it work? Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you provide some of your data and what your desired output should look like ? I guess it can be achieved using some join operations and then splitting dfs based on conditions.

Comment: You can just do `for k, g in grouped: ` where `g` will be the `partial_df`.

Comment: @Psidom - That worked, thank you so much! One quick question. When there is only one unique combination of the fields used to groupby, I do not get any groups. Is this expected behavior? Of course, it is not a problem to handle this particular situation via code but I was curious. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cast the groupby object into a list:

```
list_of_fields = ['a','b','c']
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':list('110100111'),
                   'b':list('233322233'),
                   'c':list('555444454'),
                   'd':list('xyxyxyxyy')})

grouped = df.groupby(list_of_fields)
dfs = [x[1] for x in list(grouped)]

print(dfs[0])
#   a  b  c  d
#4  0  2  4  x
#5  0  2  4  y
```